Generalization of a result of Kostant related to Gauss decomposition and Toda lattices
I found myself needing a generalization of a result of Kostant in his famous paper
B. Kostant, The solution to a generalized Toda lattice and representation theory, Adv. in Math, Volume 34, 1979, Pages 195–338.
We work in a simple Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ with rank $n$. For $w_0\in {\mathfrak h}_+$, the dominant Weyl chamber, and $f=\sum_{i=1}^n e_{-\alpha_i}$, a principal nilpotent element, denote
$$
w=f + w_0.
$$
In his Lemma 3.5.2, Kostant showed that there exists a unique element $\bar n_f(w)\in \bar N$ (the lower nilpotent subgroup) such that
$$
\operatorname{Ad}_{\bar n_f(w)} w_0 = w.
$$
Kostant didn't prove this directly, but I think what he did shows that
$$
s(\kappa)^{-1} \bar n_f(w) \in \bar N H N,
$$
so has Gauss decomposition (or LU decomposition), where $\kappa$ is the longest element in the Weyl group $W$, and $s(\kappa)\in G$ is the group element realizing it. See his equation (5.5.4).
I wonder if the same can be said for any element $\sigma\in W$ in the Weyl group. That is, can we prove that
$$
s(\sigma)^{-1} \bar n_f(w) \in \bar N H N,\quad \forall \sigma\in W?
$$
Here is an example for ${\mathfrak g}=\mathfrak{sl}_3$. Let
$$
w_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &  & \\
 & 0 & \\
& & -1
\end{pmatrix},\quad
f=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &  & \\
1 & 0 & \\
& 1&  0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
then
$$
\bar n_f(w) = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & & \\
1 & 1 & \\
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
There are enough nonzero elements in $\bar n_f(w)$ that
$$
s(\sigma)^{-1} \bar n_f(w) \in \bar N H N,\quad \forall \sigma\in W,
$$
where $s(\sigma)$ is a signed permutation matrix in this case.
I hope someone is interested in this Lie group question of some independent interest. Answers or hints are appreciated.

Is $w$ the same as $w_0$? \ Because I do not understand the claim, I am confused by "There are enough nonzero elements in $\bar n_f$ such that …."  Is $\bar n_f$ the same as $\bar n_f(w)$?  What does "enough" mean here?  Might it mean "there are enough nonzero elements in $\bar n_f$ that …"? \ Although it is surely legal, I find it very confusing in a question about Weyl-group elements to denote an element of a CSA by $w$!

@LSpice Let me edit a bit in the post. In short, $w=w_0 + f$, $\bar n_f = \bar n_f(w)$. The choice of $w_0\in {\mathfrak h}$ is Kostant's. For a group element to have Gauss decomposition, we need, in the $A_n$ case, all the principal minors need to be nonzero. That is what I meant about the nonzero elements in $\bar n_f(w)$, and they also have nonzero minors, even after the $s(\sigma)$ row permutation.

Re, thank you. Although your meaning is now clear, I will mention that what you describe would usually be phrased "there are enough nonzero elements [or entries, or components …] in $\bar n_f(w)$ that …" (no "such").

I believe that the answer to your question is yes and it follows from Proposition 8.1 in our paper The Mirković–Vilonen basis and Duistermaat–Heckman measures (with Baumann and Knutson).  The notation is our paper is a bit different from that of your question.  The notation $ n_x $ in our paper seems to be the equivalent of your $\bar n_f(w) $ (we use $ x $ for any regular element of the Cartan).  Also upper and lower triangular are switched in our paper, compared to your question.  However, once you take all that into account, I believe that our Prop 8.1 does exactly what you want.

Thank you!! It is wonderful to find this result, exactly what I needed, for a PDE question. MathOverflow is powerful, wow!

I'm amazed that it is useful for a PDE question!

It is just the Toda field theory, the 1+1 dimensional PDE version of Toda lattices.
